# Would a ramjet be able to fly at 1% of sea level atmosphere and pure oxygen?

Tags: supersonic, ramjet, scramjet

1% (0.01 atm) of the sea level pressure is a bit less pressure than at the SR-71 Blackbird's highest altitudes. If all that atmosphere was 100% oxygen (instead of 21%), would a (sc)ramjet still be able to fly in it? If not, would it be able to fly in it if Earth's gravity was lower?

Comment: Downvoter please explain why -1 so the question may be improved.

Comment: @mins Alright I rephrased it so that it doesn't sound like more appropriate to space.SE.

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort [...] or not useful". OP has not demonstrated they made any attempt at answering this question, and I don't see how this question is useful to the broader community.

Comment: @Sanchises You're right, I made an attempt to _ask_ the question instead. What should I have done to answer it? The question and its answer should be useful to the OP in the first place.

Comment: Do you mean, would the engine be able to operate, or would the aircraft be able to fly? VTC as unclear.

Comment: @RalphJ Ability to operate but I'd be curious on the ability leveled flight too. The duplicate question answers it quite well anyway.